# mfrow3d with contour3d erases previous plots

Tags: r, rgl

I'm having trouble displaying multiple 3d plots with rgl's `mfrow3d` and misc3d's `contour3d`.
In particular, plotting a new subplot will result in all previous subplots being deleted. Here is a simple example:

```
library(rgl)
library(misc3d)

# setup rgl subplots
mfrow3d(1,2)

# step into first subplot
next3d()

# Draw a ball
f <- function(x, y, z)x^2+y^2+z^2
x <- seq(-2,2,len=20)
contour3d(f,4,x,x,x)

# advance to next subplot
next3d()

# Ball with one corner removed.
contour3d(f,4,x,x,x, 
      mask = function(x,y,z) x > 0 | y > 0 | z > 0, 
      screen = list(x = 290, y = -20),
      color = "red", color2 = "white")
# the first subplot is removed
```

In the first call to `contour3d`, the first ball draws fine on the left. However, after the second call to `contour3d`, the second plot is drawn on the right, but the first plot is deleted.

[image]

What am I missing here? My hunch is that I'm missing an argument to `contour3d`, as `mfrow3d` works fine with other `*3d` plotting functions, but not with with `contour3d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like base graphics, `rgl` graphics come in two types:  low level (things like drawing points, lines, etc.) and high level (like `plot3d` or `persp3d`).  By default high level plots first advance to the next frame (by calling `next3d()`), while low level plots add to the current one.

The `misc3d::contour3d` function draws everything using low-level commands, but it assumes it has control of the full window, so instead of calling `next3d()` to advance to the next frame, it calls `clear3d()` which clears the whole window.

To work around this, you can call `next3d()` yourself (only after the first plot, you don't need it before the first one), and then tell `contour3d()` to add to the scene.  That is, change your code like this:

```
library(rgl)
library(misc3d)

# setup rgl subplots
mfrow3d(1,2)

# Draw a ball
f <- function(x, y, z)x^2+y^2+z^2
x <- seq(-2,2,len=20)
contour3d(f,4,x,x,x)

# advance to next subplot
next3d()

# Ball with one corner removed.
contour3d(f,4,x,x,x, 
          mask = function(x,y,z) x > 0 | y > 0 | z > 0, 
          screen = list(x = 290, y = -20),
          color = "red", color2 = "white", add = TRUE)
```